# How to tell the original encoding of a file

Tags: java, encoding

I have a bunch of plain text file which I downloaded from 3rd party servers.
Some of them are gibberish; the server sent the information of ENCODING1 (e.g.: UTF8), but in reality the encoding of the file was ENCODING2 (e.g.: Windows1252).

Is there a way to somehow correct these files?

I presume the files were (ENCODING1) mostly encoded in UTF8, ISO-8859-2 and Windows1252 (and I presume they were mostly saved with one of these encodings). I was thinking about re-encoding every filecontent with

`new String(String.getBytes(ENCODING1), ENCODING2)`

with all possibilites of ENCODING1 and ENCODING2 (for 3 encodings that would be 9 options)
then finding some way (for example: charachter frequency?) to tell which of the 9 results is the correct one.

Are there any 3rd party libraries for this?

I tried JChardet and ICU4J, but as far as I know both of them are only capable of detecting the encoding of the file before the step with ENCODING1 took place

Thanks,
krisy

Comment: I've got a very similar problem and it's a bit of a nightmare.  As far as I can tell there's no reliable way of doing it.  If anyone can help with this I'd be really grateful.

Comment: I recommend trying Mozilla's charset detector or a .NET port of it. http://www.mozilla.org/projects/intl/chardet.html and http://code.google.com/p/chardetsharp/

Comment: Do you need to detect the encoding in a programmatic way or can you do it out of your program?

Comment: It's worse than you think: [The Czech and Slovak Character Encoding Mess Explained](http://luki.sdf-eu.org/txt/cs-encodings-faq.html)

Comment: cheers obv, just found the java port of that mozilla library at http://jchardet.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I would like to do it in a programatic way.

Comment: How can I use JChardet for this? JChardet needs a byte[] for input but I have (the already, and - sadly - wrongly ) encoded String :-(

Comment: There is no generic way to determine what charset was used in a text file, absent "meta" information.  At best there are some ways to make a "best guess".

Comment: Convert back to byte[] using the same encoding that was used to convert to String, and hope that the encoding is reversible.

Comment: Hot Licks: that's the point - I don't have the original encoding. :-(

Comment: Note that if you have FILES (on disk), they are almost certainly encoded in some 8-bit format.  When you read them as Strings you then convert to UTF-16.  But if you received them over the net (probably as 8-bit strings) and converted to String before saving the files you have unknown_8-bit_format -> UTF16, followed by UTF16 ->some_8_bit_format.  You should at the very least be able to figure out what some_8_bit_format is, if you still have the code that did the downloading.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38527/discussion-between-krisy-and-hot-licks)

Comment: Yes, that is the case - but sadly I don't know what servers were the files downloaded from, so I don't know the original encoding :-( Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: I'd say, get the best 8-bit representation you can manage (undoing what you know how to undo) and run that through one of the recognizers.  Then go from there.

Answer (score 3):

You can use library provided by google to detect character set for a file, please see following:

```
import org.mozilla.universalchardet.UniversalDetector;

public class TestDetector
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException
    {
        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.err.println("Usage: java TestDetector FILENAME");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
        String fileName = args[0];
        java.io.FileInputStream fis = new java.io.FileInputStream(fileName);

        // (1)
        UniversalDetector detector = new UniversalDetector(null);

        // (2)
        int nread;
        while ((nread = fis.read(buf)) > 0 && !detector.isDone()) {
            detector.handleData(buf, 0, nread);
        }
        // (3)
        detector.dataEnd();

        // (4)
        String encoding = detector.getDetectedCharset();
        if (encoding != null) {
            System.out.println("Detected encoding = " + encoding);
        } else {
            System.out.println("No encoding detected.");
        }

        // (5)
        detector.reset();
    }
}
```

Read more at following [URL](http://code.google.com/p/juniversalchardet/)

You can also try `jCharDet` by sourceforge, please see following [URL](http://jchardet.sourceforge.net/)

Cheers !!

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid it won't work (actually tested, and does not work :-(); every time I use it only UTF8 is returned as the charset (it might be that the files are now UTF8 encoded, but the characters with accents are transformed into their UTF8 equivalent -> the gibberish ones, so I can not tell the original encoding)

Comment: Should have worked, please give a try to `jCharDet`, see edit.

Answer (score 1):

Inside JVM Strings are always unicode (converted by reading or creation), so `aStringVariable.getBytes(ENCODING1)` will only work for output.

For a basic understanding you should read http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html.

As mentioned in this article there is no way to know for sure which original encoding was used; due to this article e.g. Internet Explorer guesses by the frequency of different bytes.

Answer (score 0):

So the original files are in UTF8 (multibyte Unicode format), ISO-8859-2 (Latin-2) and Windows-1252 (MS Latin-1). You want to have them all in UTF-8.

First the download should not do any conversion, so the contents stay intact.
Otherwise you could only *attempt* to repair a wrong encoding, without guarantee.

Java uses Unicode for text internally. So create a String only with the correct encoding. For the file contents use `byte[]`.

The functionality available:

- If the file is in 7-bits US-ASCII then it already UTF-8
- If the file has only valid UTF-8 sequences, it most likely is UTF-8; can be tested
- Remains to distinguish between Latin-2 and MS Latin-1

The latter can be done by some statistics. For instance identifying the language by their 100 most frequent words functions rather well.

I am aware of a couple of charset detectors. That one did not seem to work might also be that the file is already corrupted. With Notepad++ or JEdit or some other encoding converting editor you might check.

```
Charset detectCharset(Path path) throws IOException {
    byte[] content = Files.readAllBytes(path);
    boolean ascii = true;
    boolean utf8 = true;
    Map<Byte, Integer> specialCharFrequencies = new TreeMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < content.length; ++i) {
        byte b = content[i];
        if (b < 0) {
            ascii = false;
            if ((b & 0xC0) == 0xC0) { // UTF-8 continuation byte
                if (i == 0 || content[i - 1] >= 0) {
                    utf8 = false;
                }
            }
            specialCharFrequencies.merge(b, 1, Integer::sum);
        }
    }
    if (ascii || utf8) {
        return StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
    }
    // ... determine by frequencies
    Charset latin1 = Charset.forName("Windows-1252");
    Charset latin2 = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-2");
    System.out.println(" B  Freq 1 2");
    specialCharFrequencies.entrySet().stream()
        .forEach(e -> System.out.printf("%02x %06d %s %s%n",
            e.getKey() & 0xFF, e.getValue(),
            new String(new byte[] {e.getKey(), 0, 1}, latin1),
            new String(new byte[] {e.getKey(), 0, 1}, latin2)));
    return null;
}
```

Illegal UTF-8 can slip through this check, but it would be easy to use a Charset decoder.